# Issue with installing SBT on Windows

Tags: java, installation, sbt

I'm installing GIT/SBT/ETC on a new Windows 10 computer. I have installed GIT and SBT and Java JDK13. I also added the appropriate JAVA_HOME and PATH variables for java.

Now when I go to do "sbt -version" I get the following output. The first time I ran it after setting the path variables correctly it did a bunch of stuff but ended with this error. Now I only get the error when I run the version command.

```
$ sbt -version
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\Users\WilliamWelch\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.6\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\Users\WilliamWelch\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.6\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/runtime/package.class)
sbt script version: 1.3.4
```

All my googling turns up using some portions of these errors is that I should use JDK 8 but that isn't even supported anymore (as evidenced by needing an account to download it) so I can't imagine whatever bug that was hasn't been fixed in SBT by now.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend you use a less recent JDK, as that might cause problems with Scala otherwise. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html -- the recommended version is 11. (your project probably uses SBT 0.13.x which uses Scala 2.10 which is clearly incompatible with JDK 13)

Comment: To clarify: your SBT script (ie. launcher) seems to be version 1.3.4, but you seem to use SBT 0.13 in your build. Still, using Java 11 should work. And of course, you can still download a Java 8 kit, e.g. from https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: You can download the Oracle 8 JDK on Windows. I couldn't get the OpenJDK 8 build to work on Windows. Only from Java 9 does it become licensed. I'd use OpenJDK from 9 onward though.